# New Google Chrome: How to avoid undesired newlines when copying CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, copy-paste

With the new version of Google Chrome, I assume they added some "move left and right to change value" feature to the CSS console.

After update, when I tried to copy paste to my file I got a super broken formatting.

Quick example:

```
    max-width: 626
px
;
```

Anyone else noticed this change? Any idea how to restore old version of this or just turn it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it's a drag..

you can work around this by using the context menu dedicated for that; right-click the desired rule in the styles tab, and choose *copy all declarations*.

here's a screenshot of that menu on this page:

[image]

Comment: Ah, i see it. And can i completly turn this feature off?

Comment: @Yarushi - not sure you can. it looks like a genuine bug, so it'll probably get fixed sometime soon (hopefully) :)